# google data studio converting silently data types?

Tags: type-conversion, looker-studio

I am consuming some external data from postgres (using google data studio):

[image]

The column is 'costperhour', why the data type appears as 'hour'? I think is a mistake...

i.e.

[image]

could it be that it just converted automatically 15, 10, 12, 8 and 10 to those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the [Data Source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6268208), it can be achieved by changing the **Type** of the `costperhour` field to the required **Type**, for example:

### From:

```
Date > Hour
```

### To:

```
Currency > USD - US Dollar ($)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/534db602-132a-4a2b-b752-e0320cc2ee58) and a GIF to demonstrate

[image]